Is it possible to programmatically click the Pair or Pair & Connect button using Accessibility Service?
I’m developing an Android app that requires interaction with the Bluetooth pairing process. When a Bluetooth pairing notification or pairing dialog appears on the screen, the user is prompted to manually click either the Pair or Pair & Connect button.
I'm trying to automate this process using an Accessibility Service in my app. Specifically, I want to programmatically click the appropriate button (Pair or Pair & Connect) when the dialog or notification appears.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Set up an AccessibilityService to detect windows and dialogs.
class MyAccessibilityService: AccessibilityService() {
companion object {
    const val TAG = "MyAccessibilityService"
}
override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent?) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent: ${Gson().toJson(event)}")
    if(event?.eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED || event?.eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED) {
        clickPairButton()
    }
}
private fun clickPairButton() {
    val rootNode = rootInActiveWindow ?: return
    Log.i(TAG, "========== clickPairButton ========== ")
    Log.i(TAG, "Root Node: ${ rootNode.className}")
    findAndClickButton(rootNode, "PAIR")
    findAndClickButton(rootNode, "PAIR & CONNECT")
}    private fun findAndClickButton(rootNode: AccessibilityNodeInfo?, s: String) {
    for(i in 0 until rootNode?.childCount!!) {
        val childNode = rootNode.getChild(i) ?: continue

        if(childNode.className.equals("android.widget.Button") &&
            childNode.text != null &&
            childNode.text.toString().equals(s, true)) {
            childNode.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK)
            Log.e(TAG, "s$s Button Clicked")
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Class: ${childNode.className}" )
        }
    }
}    override fun onInterrupt() {

}}

It seems like Accessibility service is not able to detect Pairing Dialog or I am doing it wrong.
I am able to detect buttons in my app's UI but not able to detect pairing dialog and its buttons.

The pairing request requires the user's consent. This is a security-relevant behaviour and having it automatically 'clicked' by another application without the user's consent is certainly a security problem.

It is not a problem because our app will be running on company owned devices. Normal users cannot install this app.

I don't see how your comment makes things any better. The behaviour you want is a security threat in any case.

It is not a problem because our app will be running on company owned devices. Normal users cannot install this app. ==> It doesn't change anything. Anyone can install the app anyway, and automating the process could still allow stealing or hacking neighbor's hardware.
